# Please explain to me how this CSS property removes the trailing lines from a transition

Tags: html, css

This is a bit of a long-winded question, but I hope someone can break this down for me. I have 2 questions:

1. Why a CSS property doesn't do what it should.
2. Why this particular CSS property works on an unsuspecting element, and why it doesn't work on the CSS `:hover` selector.

Created a flipcard animation. Got some graphics/trailing lines issues with transitions (in Chrome).

Doing some Googling, I found out that apparently, using `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` is supposed to fix the issue by using hardware acceleration.

However, I couldn't figure out **where** to place this CSS property. I tried placing it on the `.flipcard-container`, `.flipcard`, on the actual transition (`.flipcard-container: hover .flipcard`).

None of these removed the trailing lines caused by the animation.

## Question 1: Where can I use the `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` properly in order to take advantage of the hardware acceleration, and why does/doesn't it work there?

But, after doing even more Googling and copying someone else's code, I found adding `perspective: 600px`to the `.flipcard-container` somehow fixed the issue. And on top of that, it even makes my animation look really nice.

It shouldn't bother me so much, but it does that I cannot figure out **why this worked.**

According to the MDN docs:

> The perspective CSS property determines the distance between the z=0
>   plane and the user in order to give a 3D-positioned element some
>   perspective.

## Question 2: Why does this work in my transition so well? Shouldn't I have to place `perspective` in `.flipcard-container: hover .flipcard` instead of the `.flip-container`?

Of course, when placing it in the css `:hover` selector, the entire transition stops working. Does the `perspective` property also use hardware acceleration?

Here is the code, and thank you in advance.

```css
.flipcard-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
/* uncommenting the below property will fix the issue */
/* -webkit-perspective: 600; */

}

.flipcard-container:hover .flipcard {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.5);

}

.flipcard, .front, .back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.flipcard {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}

.front {
  background: #6093e5;
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  
}

.back {
  background: #e56060;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flipcard-container">
  <div class="flipcard">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**
You are overriding the `transform:` tags with the hardware acceleration. This causes that the animation doesn't work if you put it in.

You can use this, to archive better (more stable fps)

```
.flipcard-container:hover .flipcard {
     transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.5);
     will-change: -webkit-transition;
     will-change: transition;
}
```

it uses the new will-change property.
[More details](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/will-change)

> The will-change CSS property provides a way for authors to hint
>   browsers about the kind of changes to be expected on an element, so
>   that the browser can setup appropriate optimizations ahead of time
>   before the element is actually changed. These kind of optimizations
>   can increase the responsiveness of a page by doing potentially
>   expensive work ahead of time before they are actually required.

**Question 2**

If you look at e.g. this:
https://codepen.io/jfcorugedo/pen/bBPWaO?q=3d+turn&limit=all&type=type-pens

you see that it also uses the `perspective` tag. It is used that you can see the rotation of the box (like in your case).
If you remove it, it looks like your code. It works only on the container because the object you want to flip is wrapped in it.

If you have more questions just ask :)